# Semantic UI Calendar Modal does not pop up

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, semantic-ui

I have implemented the Semantic UI to use the calendar which is basically really great and it works perfectly. The only problem is that the calend is in a modal and when it gets triggered the Modal looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfB7K.png

I want that the calender is already poped up and I don't have to click on the "today" button to reveal the calendar.

I have read that is has to do something with the observe but I dont know how to change that and where to put that piece of code.(https://github.com/mdehoog/Semantic-UI-Calendar/issues/40)

This is my JS function:

```
function devicesForCalendar(type) {

$('#openCalView').click(function () {
    var valueArray = [];

    $('.check:checked').each(function () {
        valueArray.push($(this).val());
    });
    if (valueArray.length == 0) {
        alert("No devices selected!");
        $('#calendarInsert').fullCalendar('destroy');
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "db-functions.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { data: valueArray, change: 'chosenCalendar', type: type },
            success: function (data) {

                var events = JSON.parse(data);

                $('#calendarInsert').fullCalendar('destroy');
                $('#calendarInsert').fullCalendar({
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },
                    defaultDate: new Date(),
                    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
                    editable: true,
                    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                    events: events
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get the calendar outside the modal, you'll have to post the HTML code so we can know how the calendar design all works. To fix the problem of not having to click the `Today` button to show the calendar, the problem rests in your assignment of the `defaultDate` variable. You set it equal to a `Date` object, but that ends up coming out to the format of something like "Sat Mar 09 2019 12:08:39 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)". It needs to be in the "yyyy-mm-dd" standard ISO format. To do that, you could simply type in today's date, or do:

```
var d = new Date();
var e = d.getMonth();
if (e < 10) {
   var e2 = ("0" + e).slice(-2);
}
var f = d.getDate();
if (f < 10) {
   var f2 = ("0" + f).slice(-2);
}
var g = d.getFullYear() + "-" + e2 + "-" + f2;
// Later in the code
defaultDate: g,
```

Notice I use the `slice()` method to put leading zeros on the single digits, as `Date.getMonth()` and `Date.getDate()` return digits like 2 and 7.

Comment: No I want that it looks like this when the Modal gets opened: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjX4s.png and not like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfB7K.png

Comment: I know, and that's because your `defaultDate` variable was not in the right format that the calendar didn't appear. My code was meant to fix that - did you try it?

Comment: Put all of the variable declarations and if statements right below `function devicesForCalendar(type) {`, so they are global variables defined in a scope in a syntax that you couldn't define in AJAX yet AJAX can reference them, and then just simply replace `new Date()` with `g` for the `defaultDate` variable.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but even when I try a static date like '2016-06-05' for example it is still not working :(

Comment: Sorry, then I'm not sure what the issue is...unless maybe you didn't put the date in quotes